# xml attribute value whitespace throws an error php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following xml:

```
<ATTRIBUTES NAME="Size" ATTRIBUTEID="2">
    <ATTRIBUTEVALUES VALUE="16" TITLE="Small" PRICEADJUST="0.00"/>
    <ATTRIBUTEVALUES VALUE="16" TITLE="Small" PRICEADJUST="0.00"/>
    <ATTRIBUTEVALUES VALUE="32" TITLE="X Large" PRICEADJUST="0.00"/>
    <ATTRIBUTEVALUES VALUE="18" TITLE="Large" PRICEADJUST="0.00"/>
    <ATTRIBUTEVALUES VALUE="17" TITLE="Medium" PRICEADJUST="0.00"/>
</ATTRIBUTES>
```

and am reading the xml using the line:

```
$option_value = (string)$xml->ATTRIBUTES->ATTRIBUTEVALUES[$x]['TITLE']
```

where $x is part of a for loop and I have loaded the xml using simplexml_load_file.  There is a space in the TITLE="X Large" and my code is throwing an error.  Is there any way to read this attribute value with the space intact?  Or process the attribute value in some way before saving it to a variable?

Comment: Show some real code, maybe then we can help

Comment: And include the error message please.